# SQLAlchemy foreign key lazy loading

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a basic one to many relationship:

```
class Term(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'term'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Node(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'node'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  term = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('term.id'))
```

But when I load the Node object, access the "term" property, I just get the numeric term id, not the Term object.

```
node = session.query(Node).filter(Node.id == 1).one()
print node.term # 123
```

How do I get Foreign Key fields to lazy load the object?

Thanks very much.
Ben

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because your `term` attribute is a `Column`, sqlalchemy maps it as that column's value.  You can get sqlalchemy to actually load the referent row by using `relationship`:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

class Term(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'term'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Node(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'node'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  term = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('term.id'))
  related_term = relationship(Term, backref="nodes")
```

Because `my_node.related_term` looks a bit odd, I tend to prefer a naming convention of having the column called `table_column` instead of just `table`, so that I can also name the `relationship` attribute after the table, instead of inventing some other, odd name.

Comment: Brilliant. That sorts it, and I'll use that naming tip too. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use the returned value of `node.term` for a new query, to get the related objects:

```
node = session.query(Node).filter(Node.id == 1).one()
related_term = session.query(Term).filter(Term.id == node.term).one()
```

Comment: This is very much the opposite of what Ben is asking for, explicitly loading this object largely negates the value of using an ORM, where you can ignore the on disk persistence of the data and treat them as regular python objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'm pretty much a newbie in SQLAlchemy haha. Will be fun to learn from you, sir!